# Can stress matrix be complex?

Tags: complex-numbers, stress-strain

Stress matrix gives the values of physical deformation due to stress. So, it is usually real. But in complex spaces are physically realizable spaces. Then, is it possible to have complex strain matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a complex stress matrix too if the material you are analyzing happens to be a visco-elastic material. Only for a purely elastic material, we have a real stress matrix.

Comment: Do this complex stress matrix produces real strain or complex strain? Because, the elastic modulus will definitely be complex if the stress is complex. Will the strain be too complex?

Comment: You know, strain cannot physically be a complex number, it is just in mathematics. The use of complex numbers is simply to convey that there is phase difference (time lag) in the stress response of a material 
for a given strain input. Such materials are called viscoelastic materials.